# Flatten nested list of dict into Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary, nested

I'm reading the below json structure

```
{"response":
    {"GDUEACWF":
        {"2018-06-01":
            [{"groupwide_market":"Developed Markets",
            "weights":0.8794132316432903},
            {"groupwide_market":"Developed Markets",
            "weights":0.8794132316432903}],
        "2018-06-02":
            [{"groupwide_market":"Developed Markets",  
            "weights":0.8794132316432903},
            {"groupwide_market":"Developed Markets",
            "weights":0.8794132316432903}]}}}
```

and trying to flatten it into a Pandas dataframe of the below format.

```
|data_date  |groupwide_market  |weights
|2018-06-01 |Developed Markets |0.08794132316432903
```

I tried to do this by looping through each list in each k,v pair by using the below codes. It does work, however, it is also very slow. 100k rows of data takes more than 30 minutes to generate.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
#concatenating each line of the list within each dict cell
for k1,v1 in data['response'][mnemonic].items():
    for ele in v1:
        df_temp = pd.concat({k2: pd.Series(v2) for k2, v2 in ele.items()}).transpose()
        df_temp['data_date'] = k1
        df = df.append(df_temp,ignore_index=True)
df.columns = [x[0] for x in df.columns]
```

May I know if there is a more efficient way to do this? Tried reading up on the documentation and examples for json_normalize but couldn't figure out apply it in this context.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the dictionary as `data`, we can proceed as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame([(date, *nodes.values()) for info in data["response"].values()
              for date, values in info.items() for nodes in values],
              columns=["date", "market", "weight"])
```

Using as input the given response, the output is as follows:
[image]